# Getting 'certificate has expired' error while running meteor

Tags: visual-studio-code, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts, angular-meteor

```
   While downloading accounts-base@1.2.11...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading accounts-password@1.3.0...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading alanning:roles@1.2.15...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading aldeed:collection2@2.10.0...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading aldeed:collection2-core@1.2.0...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading aldeed:schema-deny@1.1.0...:
```

Even tried set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 and then run meteor. But still getting error.

Answer (score 12):

https://docs.meteor.com/expired-certificate.html:

> If you are getting errors like Connection error (certificate has expired) when running Meteor commands it means that you are running a version of Meteor older than v1.9.

> A workaround, for now, is to run all the meteor commands with the following environment variable NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED, for example ...

I suspect you didn't set the env var correctly. Either `export` it or set it right on the command line:

```
NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 meteor
```

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error

```
export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
```

tried this and it worked